# Is it legal to move the vertical bar in an augmented matrix?

Tags: matrices, notation

Say I am solving a system of linear equations using Gauss reduction. I have got it to this point:
$$\left[\begin{array}{ccc|c}
 1 & 0 & -1 & 1 \\
 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0
 \end{array}\right]$$
It seems intuitive to me from basic arithmetic that it should be legal to do:
$$\left[\begin{array}{cc|cc}
 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
 0 & 1 & -1 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0
 \end{array}\right]$$
as a step to writing a line equation in 3-space:
$$\begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \\ z \end{pmatrix}
= z\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ -1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}
+ \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} $$

However, is moving the vertical bar considered a legal *matrix* operation? (And is there a more technical name for the vetical bar that I ought to be using?)

Comment: The vertical bar is not formally part of the matrix at all -- it is just there to help you keep track of what you're doing, namely: applying the same row operations to the coefficient matrix and the constant column vector. So moving the bar is not a "legal matrix operation" at, because it is not a matrix operation at all.

Comment: Before you can ask whether it's legal, you have to specify what it means to have 2 columns on the right side of the vertical bar.  Usually the augmented matrix [A|b], where A is a matrix and b is a column, is an abbreviated version of the equation Ax=b.  But now you have matrices on both sides, so it's not clear what that means any more.  The "equation" interpretation of Ax=b would mean, in your example above, that x has to be a 2 by 2 matrix.  That is totally different from what you started with, in which x was a 3 by 1 matrix.

Comment: What do you expect to achieve by doing this? It seems to me that you are misunderstanding something...

Comment: @Mariano Suárez-Alvarez The idea is simply to interpose another step to reduce the risk of making a mistake. I could always move out of matrix notation, but going out of it and then back into it means that to be more explicit I am actually doing more work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have thot about this more, with the help of the comments above, which I will cite in my answer.

The answer is **no, moving the vertical bar is not a valid matrix operation**, because:

1. It is not a matrix operation at all (Henning Makholm)
2. If it were to be defined as a matrix operation, it would be rather ambiguous (Ted)

However, the underlying matrix  operations that were behind the idea are valid. The idea is just as
$$\left[\begin{array}{ccc|c}
 1 & 0 & -1 & 1 \\
 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0
 \end{array}\right]$$
implies

$$\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
 1 & 0 & -1 \\
 0 & 1 & 1 \\
 0 & 0 & 0
 \end{array}\right]
\left[\begin{array}{c}
x \\ y \\ z
\end{array}\right] = 
\left[\begin{array}{c}
1 \\ 0 \\ 0
\end{array}\right]$$

So
$$\left[\begin{array}{cc|cc}
 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
 0 & 1 & -1 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0
 \end{array}\right]$$
would imply

$$\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 \\
 0 & 0
 \end{array}\right]
\left[\begin{array}{c}
x \\ y
\end{array}\right] = 
z \left[\begin{array}{c}
1 \\ -1 \\ 0
\end{array}\right]
+ \left[\begin{array}{c}
1 \\ 0 \\ 0
\end{array}\right]$$

which is legal, and solves the problem of switching in and out of the matrix notation and should provide a good intermediate step, as desired, even if it is not quite as succinct. It  also makes the next steps much more clear: do the matrix multiplication on the LHS, add
$$ \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ z \end{pmatrix} $$
to both sides of the equation, and simplify.